# Why Google Places Autocomplete does not hide/show automatically?

Tags: react-native

I just follow and example of the repository and it did not show/hide, it just stay there, over half the screen, it is very annoying.

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder='Search'
      minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
      autoFocus={false}
      returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
      keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
      listViewDisplayed='undefined'    // true/false/undefined
      fetchDetails={true}
      renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
      onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
        console.log(data, details);
      }}

      getDefaultValue={() => ''}

      query={{
        // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
        key: 'YOUR API KEY',
        language: 'en', // language of the results
        types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
      }}

      styles={{
        textInputContainer: {
          width: '100%'
        },
        description: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        predefinedPlacesDescription: {
          color: '#1faadb'
        }
      }}

      currentLocation={true} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
      currentLocationLabel="Current location"
      nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
      GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
        // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
      }}
      GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
        // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
        rankby: 'distance',
        type: 'cafe'
      }}
      
      GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
        // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
        fields: 'formatted_address',
      }}

      filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
      predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}

      debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
      renderLeftButton={()  => <Image source={require('path/custom/left-icon')} />}
      renderRightButton={() => <Text>Custom text after the input</Text>}
    />
```

I'd like to show/hide it whenever the user choose an option of the list or touch another part of the app.

Also I'd like to know how to get the info of the choosen option to pass to a method to create routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have set `listViewDisplayed` to `undefined`.

You should set it to `auto`. That's it.

Hope it helps you.